# Is it possible to run multiple apps with different angular versions on one page?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to run multiple angular2 applications on one page. Additionally they should run in different versions.

I know: Angular is designed to be a single page application framework and so the use case I described is pretty exotic. Nevertheless I want to know if it is theoretically possible?

I've already managed to get it run, my only problem was, that zone-js has a variable on the global namespace and throws an error when getting loaded more than once. When I load zone-js only once, the two angular applications run side-by-side. You can see the different angular versions in the dom.
[image: ng-version2.3.1]
[image: ng-version2.4.6]

But now my question(s) in more detail: Do I have to worry when running two angular applications running side-by-side on one page? Does it make sense to load other dependencies only once? What when maybe angular major version 4 depend on another zone-js major version - I can't load them both on one page? Is it OK to load all webpack bundles twice (inline.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js, main.bundle.js)?

Comment: you can surely find ways to make this work by hacks or workarounds, but your solution would likely be *very brittle*.  It doesn't really make sense to do this anyway;  You are likely to have issues, where updating something in one of the apps causes something unexpected to happen in the other. If this is the same project, why would you not take the time to integrate the multiple pieces?   and if you are just trying to re-use some components, then there are ways to design re-usable components....

Comment: the ideal would be: different apps on a platform which are isolated from each other and therefore run regardless of the dependencies of the other apps

but that's why I've asked: does have angular other "global" dependencies which would interfere each other apart from zone-js? if not you wouldn't have the problem "where updating something in one of the apps causes something unexpected to happen in the other"

.. the goal would be, that you can develop new apps with new angular version and don't necessarily have to migrate the other (finished) apps to the newer angular version immediately

Comment: I think you'll have quite some difficulties with the router part of both versions. Both apps would change and read the browser URL. I don't think that's going to be pretty.

Comment: based on the question and the comments you've made, you seem to have an unusual idea about what an "app" is.... and what do you mean by "platform", exactly?  angular is a browser framework, and it isn't really possible to make more than one JavaScript script be "isolated" from another, in the sense you are trying to suggest....

Comment: and yes, angular has, in context of what you are describing here, many "global" dependencies on things like the DOM, browser history, network services, and more.  @DavidWalschots provided one of many examples which would make two apps on one browser page very challenging.

Comment: ultimately, the more you describe, the more this *feels like* an XY Question.  You aren't really describing a problem to be solved, you are describing a potential solution to an unknown problem.  "different apps on a platform" doesn't really make sense in context of how angular works, so it's more likely that you are trying to approach your problem by applying some understanding of some other environment which isn't equatable here.  Perhaps describing *why* you think you need to have multiple different apps would help?

Comment: I mean, "develop other apps without migrating other finished apps" makes sense, but I don't see how that relates to "hosting two apps on a single page".

Comment: From my point of view this questions is perfectly clear and valid. Is it possible to run serveral angular apps with different angular version on one page - e.g. header, main content and sidebar of a page are implemented as different angular apps (composite ui in a microservice environment)? Especially in the context of the angular labs project "Angular Elements" this questions should get more importance. With vue and react it seems possible to scope the framework version per application instance. A answer on this question would be great.

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to solve a similar problem and we found a [meta-framework](https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa) that we found satisfactorily manages micro front end (SPAs) In fact, we were able to bring in other SPAs that were built by different teams with different JS frameworks with little to no effort.

There may be a lot of reasons against doing this as such an app may not exactly be referred to as performant. I would say the reason for undertaking such a thing in our case was need for federated development: we have lots of small teams not which are not co-located and independent as far as delivery timelines that contribute to our gargantuan app which was earlier built on .net platform as a monolithic MV* webapp.