# Is it possible to have angular 7 packaged module within my platform/main app which is in angular 6 (also has other apps with angular 6)

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-material, angular6, angular-ui

I have common angular 6 (my main/platform app - which we deploy and our users access it) - which basically hosts multiple different angular 6 apps within it (basically bunch of other apps are packaged and hosted within my main/platform app). I am developing a new app (would like to build with angular (material) 7 - but dont want to migrate rest of the apps as they are already tested and working. (may migrate them later).

**Question:** Is it possible to have different modules (which are basically packaged with different angular versions - my case is - new packaged module will be in 7, and whereas the main app and rest of the modules are already in 6)?

**Note:** just to clarify i can build my new app in angular 7 locally. But eventually i want to package it and host it in my main app (we call it platform app). Which is in angular 6 and it has other packages/modules which are already in 6.

It will be great if someone can provide some guidence and reference for this. I have searched and found [Is it possible to run multiple apps with different angular versions on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179061/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-apps-with-different-angular-versions-on-one-page) . But the answer is redirecting me to: https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa

But somehow i feel like this should be general use case as its not possible to always migrate all the modules (packages) to newer version to maintian and build things.

Please do note that i do know how to upgrade app to new versions (as its straigght forward: https://update.angular.io/ - i am looking for references to have two angular packages/modules side by side (6 and 7 specifically) in my app.

Comment: You can install Angular 7 just on the specific folder in which you are having Angular 7 project

Comment: I can individually develop the app in angular 7. but the app will eventually packaged and hosted via my main app (lets call it platform app) which is already hosting other apps. All of them are in in Angular 6